# android map overlay

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new android developer working on google map.

i have no idea to display marker on map on click event and also automatically to current location.

Answer (score 3):

oooook well

Here is a tutorial to [show a marker](http://chrisblunt.com/2010/08/12/android-map-view-double-taps-and-overlay-markers/) on double tap. You can do this for single tap easily, but that may be annoying for the user.

and [this](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=148) is a tutorial to get your current location.

See ? everything was one google search away. *hint hint*

Comment: thanx dear i get the sollution.