# Add marker on google map on touched location in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Can anyone help me in the following task:

I want to add a marker in google map in android.

The functionality has to be like this that a pop up  window have to be shown to add the touched location as a marker.

I was referring the below tutorial in that they add the marker through hard coding.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

I want it that to be done using onclck on the map.

Comment: try this link: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: Check the answer, possible duplicate of [android map overlay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268884/android-map-overlay)

Comment: either this: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch/

Comment: Hey, I executed all the above methods. but none of them is allowing me to add a marker on click... Please answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `MapView` you must use `onTouch` instead of `onClick`. The `motionEvent` that this event fires, has the touch coordinates so with the `getProjection()` method from `MapView` you can convert the touch coordinates into lat and long to put the `Overlay` (`Marker`) on the map.

Answer (score 5):

I used Google Maps API v2 and the solution is given below:

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {          
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude))
            .title("New Marker");           
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);            
        System.out.println(point.latitude + "---" + point.longitude);   
    }
});
```